# Why will Visual Studio not Format my HTML doc?

Tags: html, visual-studio, format, visual-studio-2019

The HTML in my WebForm aspx file looks like a rhinoceros got loose in there going after some poachers.

I tried Edit > Advanced > Format Document, but got this:

[image]

What is wrong with line 29? It's no different than many others around it:

[image]

Here is the code up to there and a little beyond, for context:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Flix4Fams_WebForms.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Flix 4 Fams</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- My stuff below here to "</form>" -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      [Ads Left side]
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bluebackground">
      <div class="middlerow">
      <h5>
      Select Genres
      </h5>      
      <p>  
      
      <input type="checkbox" id="ckbxAllGenres" checked="checked"></input>
      <label for="ckbxAllGenres">All</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ckbxAction"</input>
      <label for="ckbxAction">Action</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ckbxAdventure"</input>
      <label for="ckbxAdventure">Adventure</label>
   . . .
```

Comment: Actually, it tells me it needs to be this way: <input type="checkbox" id="ckbxAction" />

Comment: What tells you it needs to be this way?  It's not valid HTML.  You have two malformed `<input>` tags.

Comment: Intellisense; I'll post the message. It now works / gets formatted.

Comment: Actually, it seems you're using XHTML, they should be self closing tags like `<input id="foo" />`  Why are you still using XHTML instead of html5 these days?

Comment: Not only that, but you're mixing the html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` with a xhtml namespace declaration in the `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the input tag needs to be ended with "/>":

[image]